# Macro not Working in Itemize-Block

Tags: macros, itemize

I want to write an estimation of effort for one of out clients. The client wants a few changes so I am estimating the required time for every change. I could sum up the efforts manually but that doesnt seem very smooth so I tried following:

I added this at the top of my document:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\FullEffort{0}
\newcommand{\AddEffort}[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{\FullEffort+#1}
    \renewcommand{\FullEffort}{\pgfmathresult}
}
```

At the very end of my document I tested the the functionality like this:

```
\section{Summary}
\AddEffort{5}
\AddEffort{2}
Full Effort: \FullEffort\ h
```

Which prints `Full Effort: 7 h` so it seems to work.

But as soon as I use the `\AddEffort{x}` inside an `\begin{itemize}` it does not add the number of hours.

```
\section{Security}
\subsection{Reset Passwords via Email}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Problem}\\
        Current admins can change the password of users.
    \item \textbf{Solution}\\
        Send an email with the new password to the accounts-email.
    \item \textbf{Effort}\\
        5 h \AddEffort{5}
\end{itemize}
```

The `\AddEffort{5}` inside the above `itemize` is ignored. And `Full Effort: 7 h` is still printed at the end of the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A [full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (i.e. a document that is instantly compilable) is normally preferred over code snippets, so we save time piecing them together and writing the framework for what you already have there.

Comment: Unrelated Question: So the MWE is the problem isolated, but still a .tex file, am I right?

Comment: Precisely, it is a file that can be copied-and-pasted and run while still exhibiting the issue at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code

```
\newcommand\FullEffort{0}
\newcommand{\AddEffort}[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{\FullEffort+#1}
    \renewcommand{\FullEffort}{\pgfmathresult}
}
```

has two problems:

- After `\AddEffort` `\FullEffort` expands to `\pgfmathresult`. This macro indeed contains the result, but only right after `\AddEffort`. Each further unrelated call of `\pgfmathparse` will overwrite `\pgfmathresult` and then `\FullEffort` will also change its result. This can be fixed by using `\let`. Then `\FullEffort` will have the meaning of `\pgfmathresult` and `\pgfmathresult` can be changed afterwards.

  ```
  \let\FullEffort\pgfmathresult
  ```
- The effect of `\renewcommand` is local. If `\FullEffort` is changed inside a group and environments like `itemize` are such groups, the previous meaning before the start of the group will be restored, when the group ends. Since you want to have the total result at the end of the document, `\FullEffort` should be a global resource:

  ```
  \global\let\FullEffort\pgfmathresult
  ```

  Now, `\AddEffort` can be used inside groups and `\FullEffort` will keep its meaning after closing the group.

**Summary:**

```
\newcommand\FullEffort{0}
\newcommand{\AddEffort}[1]{% comment line ends to avoid unwanted spaces
    \pgfmathparse{\FullEffort+#1}%
    \global\let\FullEffort\pgfmathresult
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems of your code were mentioned by Heiko. The third problem is that you needn't load tikz if you want only advance the number to the number. We have `\advance` primitive and we need not to load tens thousands of lines of the code (of course, when we accept the limit of 2*10^9 as a maximal number).

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\FullEffort{0}
\def\AddEffort#1{\tmpnum=\FullEffort
                 \advance\tmpnum by#1
                 \xdef\FullEffort{\the\tmpnum}%
}
```

Or using eTeX primitives (eTeX is in LaTeX activated):

```
\def\FullEffort{0}
\def\AddEffort#1{\xdef\FullEffort{\the\numexpr\FullEffort+#1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `expl3` you have a clearer syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\FullEffort{}
 {% print the value (it's fully expandable)
  \int_to_arabic:n { \g_chibi_effort_int }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddEffort}{m}
 {% globally update the variable's value
  \int_gadd:Nn \g_chibi_effort_int { #1 }
 }
\int_new:N \g_chibi_effort_int % allocate the variable
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}
\AddEffort{5}
\AddEffort{2}
Full Effort: \FullEffort\ h
Which prints Full Effort: 7 h so it seems to work.

\section{Security}
\subsection{Reset Passwords via Email}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Problem}\\
        Current admins can change the password of users.
    \item \textbf{Solution}\\
        Send an email with the new password to the accounts-email.
    \item \textbf{Effort}\\
        5 h \AddEffort{5}
\end{itemize}

Full Effort: \FullEffort.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\FullEffort` just prints the value of the counter (integer variable) that's (globally) updated by `\AddEffort`.

If you want to support also non integer values, just change all `int` into `fp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\FullEffort{}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { \g_chibi_effort_fp }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddEffort}{m}
 {
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_chibi_effort_fp { #1 }
 }
\fp_new:N \g_chibi_effort_fp
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}
\AddEffort{5}
\AddEffort{2.5}
Full Effort: \FullEffort\ h
Which prints Full Effort: 7.5 h so it seems to work.

\section{Security}
\subsection{Reset Passwords via Email}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Problem}\\
        Current admins can change the password of users.
    \item \textbf{Solution}\\
        Send an email with the new password to the accounts-email.
    \item \textbf{Effort}\\
        4.5 h \AddEffort{4.5}
\end{itemize}

Full Effort: \FullEffort.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am fairly new to Tex and I am sorry, but I think your solution is harder to understand.